# Lighting up object on mouse over

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to highlight meshes (animated characters etc) in my game on a mouse-over event.
They have multiple textures and sometimes skin.

I thought I would wrap them into a ShaderMaterial and on hit-test change uniforms to brighten it up with a fragment shader.

To do this, can I somehow just manipulate the regular shading?
Can I mix multiple materials, making my shader take color values from the standard shader and just tweak them?
Or do I need whole separate render pass and blend it with composer?

Or maybe just something else entirely, like ambient light applied to just one object/shader?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you could change the whole material/shader on mouse over, although i guess this is somewhat performance intensive, depending on the number of switches the user usually does and thwat the rest of your app is doing. What i used once is the emissive color of the regular phong material with       material.emissive.setRGB() for example. This will give you some nice effects, too.

Comment: The problem is that I'm looking for a solution that would be somewhat material-independent. I'm using phong materials for some objects and lambert for others. But I'll take a look if they have something in common I can modify.
Thanks for an interesting idea, it might actually be the solution I was looking for. I'll let you know.

Comment: Cool, it works pretty well, with both types of materials and even with textures. So I guess you nailed it. :) Thanks a lot.
Here you can see the result: http://eskel.cz/preview/Lighten/

Comment: @GuyGood Please post it as an answer, I will flag it as correct.

Comment: Only problem I have with is it that I would have to clone that material for each object, because otherwise I would change it for all at once. And since I'm doing something like a voxel engine, that means hundreds of material clones (with multiple texture maps), to change one property. :(

Comment: Clone? Why not just change the emissive color on the fly and "onMouseDown" just change it back to black?  You just have to get yourself the object's material on mouseover, haven't you?

Comment: @GuyGood when I have the same material applied to multiple scene objects (not cloned), they point to the same material object, so when I change the value it changes for all objects (with the material) in the scene.  

  Only other way I can think of is to clone the material only on mouse over, but that doesnt really solve the problem, just postpone it.

Comment: I see, of course, sorry. Well, i had the same problems, i agreed with my project to settle on a complete different highlight material, this way i have 1 "Selection Material" and i just apply it on mouse over. Maybe a second idea that  is feasible is to only get the texture uniform from the material if you want to keep the texture? Something like "selectionMaterial.map = obj.mat.map" to just change this on the fly and keep the rest as 1 selection material?

Comment: @GuyGood yeah, both of those sound like it might work. Thanks a lot for responding. I wish I could give you some karma or something. You should post the first post as an answer so I can flag it as solution.

Comment: I guess the best solution would be to do an outline, like most games do. But I found that to be much harder. Mixing shader passes etc. I guess I'll post a separate question for that, once I get down some basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

repost, see comments for details/discussion:

"you could change the whole material/shader on mouse over, although i guess this is somewhat performance intensive, depending on the number of switches the user usually does and what the rest of your app is doing. What i used once is the emissive color of the regular phong material with material.emissive.setRGB() for example. This will give you some nice effects, too".

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of this that you can probably learn a lot from. Take a look at their source:

- [Mouse over meshes](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html)
- [Interactive cubes](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I missed the first one. Anyway, we figured out something very similar, updating emissive value of the material, instead of base color. (to make it work with textures)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what GuyGood said, if you do indeed decide to use `.setRGB()` on your material you need to use the values of **R**ed **G**reen **B**lue ranging from `0` to `1` as documented in the [Three.js Documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color)

Or if you prefer, like I do, the `.setHex()` function also exists.