# Achieve blinking effect in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I want to add animation to an object so it "blinks" when something happens. How can I do this in three.js?

I tried the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
       object.material.color.setHex( 0xffffff );
     }else{
       object.material.color.setHex( 0x000000 );
     }
}
```

But the object always stays black.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Well if you are heading this route you can simply have a timer to return the object to its former color

Comment: maybe see this for the effect you want to achieve:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065329/lighting-up-object-on-mouse-over/23090087#23090087

Comment: Thanks @GuyGood that's the effect I was searching for...